# Best practices for designing a simple element to be used in many places, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

What are the best practices for designing a simple component, for example a border with a background, rounded corners and a textblock with specific styling inside? What I need to be able to do is add this component on many different objects (basically a styled label for the items). The easiest way to design such a thing, in my opinion, is via XAML, but how do I create more of these objects from the code behind?

Another option would of course to just write it all in code, but it is much slower to design the look by just looking at code. I tried googling around a bit but I suppose I am simply not figuring out the correct keywords because I was unable to find anything of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are multiple ways of doing this. Depends on what exactly you want to achieve. You would want to read up on the following in WPF

[1. UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx)

[2. CustomControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx)

[3. Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

[4. Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

[5. Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ContentControl and set its template. Your template would be the border/background/rounded corners etc...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <Border>
        ...
           <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        ...
    </Border>
</DataTemplate >
```

You'd use it like this:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" Content="blah blah" />
```